# System.assertion failed in test class

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am updating the status of case to closed whenever a ledger record is created.
The logic is working fine but the issue is in the test class that assertion is failing....

Main Class:

```
public class CaseLedgerHelper{
  Set<Id> ledgerIDSet = new Set<Id>();
  Set<Id> caseIDSet = new Set<Id>();
  Set<Case> casesToUpdate = new Set<Case>();
  List<Case> casesToUpdateLedger = new List<Case>();

  private static final String caseStatus = 'Closed'; 


  Public void onAfterInsert(List<Ledger__c> ledgerID){
          for(Ledger__c rcpt: ledgerID){
            ledgerIDSet.add(rcpt.id);
          } 

          List<Ledger__c> listOfCases= new List<Ledger__c>([SELECT ID, CaseID__r.Id FROM Ledger__c WHERE ID IN: ledgerIDSet]);
             for(Ledger__c CaseId: listOfCases){
               caseIDSet.add(CaseId.CaseID__r.Id);
             }
             if(caseIDSet != null){
                  List<case> caseList = new List<case>([SELECT Id, status FROM case WHERE ID IN: caseIDSet]);
                     for (Case caseUpdate: caseList){
                         caseUpdate.status = caseStatus;
                         casesToUpdate.add(caseUpdate);
                     }

                     if(casesToUpdate.size() > 0){

                         for(Case casesToUpdateSet : casesToUpdate){
                             casesToUpdateLedger.add(casesToUpdateSet);
                         }
                         if(casesToUpdateLedger.size()>0){
                                  Database.update(casesToUpdateLedger,false);
                         }
                     }   
             } 
       }             
  }
```

TEST CLASS:

```
@isTest
private class Case_Test {

    @isTest 
    private static void onAfterInsrt() {

        // prepare test data
        ID refundRecordtypeID = Schema.SObjectType.Ledger__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(SYSTEM.label.RECEIPT_RECORDTYPE).getRecordTypeID(); 

        List<case> caseDataList = new List<case>();
        for(Integer i=0;i<20;i++){
            Case caseData = new Case(Status='Open', Origin='Email');
            caseDataList.add(caseData);
        }

        Database.insert(caseDataList, false);

        List <Ledger__c> receiptList = new List <Ledger__c>();

        for(Integer j=0;j<20;j++){
            Case caseID = caseDataList[j];

            Ledger__c receipt = new Ledger__c();
            receipt.RecordTypeId = refundRecordtypeID;
            receipt.Status__c = 'Open';
            receipt.CaseID__c = caseID.id;

            receiptList.add(receipt);
        }
        Test.startTest();

        Database.insert(receiptList, false) ;

        Test.stopTest();


        for(Case CaseIdSet: caseDataList){
            CaseIdSet=[SELECT Status FROM CASE WHERE Id =: CaseIdSet.id];
            System.debug('CaseIdSet-------->'+CaseIdSet);
            System.debug('Status -------->'+Case.Status);
           ASSSERTION SHOULD BE STATUS CLOSED BUT STATUS IS OPEN ALWAYS



        } 
    }

}
```

Comment: The test class you've posted does not contain any assertions. `Case.Status` is not a reference to a field on `CaseIdSet`, so that doesn't tell you anything.

Comment: It appears your class is a helper for a trigger that operates on `Ledger` AfterInsert. Is that the case? You may want to make certain you've provided all the required fields necessary to create your case before you insert them. In particular, it appears to me, that ContactId is missing. Your org may have additional validation rules that are preventing your records from inserting. Check your debug logs to make certain. You should also requery the records using the Ids from your original list after test.stopTest.

Answer (score 5):

(Don't know why your test isn't working.)

Something to consider in future is that where you can you should avoid unnecessary queries, mainly to stay clear of governor limits. And generally less lines of code are easier to write and easier to review for correctness.

If I understand your logic correctly, the work could be done done without the two queries like this:

```
public void onAfterInsert(List<Ledger__c> ledgers) {

    Set<Id> caseIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (Ledger__c ledger: ledgers) {
        if (ledger.CaseID__c != null) caseIds.add(ledger.CaseID__c);
    }

    List<Case> cases = new List<Case>();
    for (Id caseId : caseIds) {
        cases.add(new Case(Id = caseId, Status = 'Closed'));
    }
    update cases;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It isn't entirely clear what question you're actually asking, but I'll go out on a limb and say it's something like "how can I make this test work?"

I'll be honest with you, your code was not easy to read. I have issues with your variable names and some slices of code that appear to not do any real work.

- Why is a `Ledger__c` record called a receipt?
- Why is a `List<Ledger__c>` given the variable name `listOfCases` (it is a list, but not of `Cases`)
- In your test method, why is the `Case` loop variable called `CaseIdSet` (it's not an Id, nor a set)

Fixing those probably won't solve your issues, but it should make it easier to diagnose what the problem is.

If I had to take a guess at what's going wrong, I'd guess that it has something to do with all of your DML calls that use `Database.insert()` and `Database.update()` with allOrNone = false. **This is probably hiding the errors that are cropping up and causing your unexpected results.**

I'll copy/paste your trigger handler class, and add my commentary:

```
public class CaseLedgerHelper{
    // I think this variable can be removed
    Set<Id> ledgerIDSet = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Id> caseIDSet = new Set<Id>();
    Set<Case> casesToUpdate = new Set<Case>();
    // I think this variable can be removed
    List<Case> casesToUpdateLedger = new List<Case>();

    // Doesn't seem like this accomplishes anything
    // Do you expect that the desired case status will ever change?
    // Is this ever used more than once?
    private static final String caseStatus = 'Closed'; 

    // Why call the parameter ledgerId?
    // This parameter name is confusing.
    // It's not a single item, and it's not an Id.
    // "insertedLedgers" would be more appropriate (they're Ledger__c records,
    //   and the plural indicates that it's a collection)
    public void onAfterInsert(List<Ledger__c> ledgerID){

        // This is fine at first glance, but I'm not sure it's really needed.
        // I'll go into more detail further down.
        for(Ledger__c rcpt: ledgerID){
            ledgerIDSet.add(rcpt.id);
        } 

        // Why is this called listOfCases?
        // They're Ledgers, not Cases.
        // "queriedLedgers" would be more appropriate, I think
        List<Ledger__c> listOfCases= new List<Ledger__c>([SELECT ID, CaseID__r.Id FROM Ledger__c WHERE ID IN: ledgerIDSet]);

        // If all you're doing is adding the Id of the related case, then
        //   all the code above this point serves no purpose.
        // You could simply iterate over the List<Ledger__c> that this method takes
        //   as input, and add Ledger__c.CaseId__c.
        // Ledger__c.CaseId__c === Ledger__c.CaseID__r.Id
        // No need to query anything.
        for(Ledger__c CaseId: listOfCases){
            caseIDSet.add(CaseId.CaseID__r.Id);
        }

        // caseIDSet is initialized to new Set<Id>() when an instance of this class
        //   is instantiated.
        // caseIDSet will never be null (though it may be empty)
        if(caseIDSet != null){

            // Technically speaking, this query is not required.
            // If you have the Id of the Case, you can specify it in the SObject
            //   constructor like "Case c = new Case(Id = caseId)".
            // Your current method works fine, but I'm always looking for ways
            //   to get rid of queries where possible (especially in triggers)
            List<case> caseList = new List<case>([SELECT Id, status FROM case WHERE ID IN: caseIDSet]);

            // This seems appropriate.
            // Also has the only usage of "caseStatus", so declaring that static
            //   variable didn't really save any time or typing.
            // If you do access static variables, it's best practice to include
            //   the name of the class (because this is an instance method, not
            //   a static method).
            // i.e. CaseLedgerHelper.caseStatus
            for (Case caseUpdate: caseList){
                caseUpdate.status = caseStatus;
                casesToUpdate.add(caseUpdate);
            }

            // I'm not sure if checking the size of a list before performing DML
            //   on it really accomplishes anything.
            // Salesforce may be smart enough to not even dock you a DML call from
            //   your limits.
            if(casesToUpdate.size() > 0){

                // You're iterating over one list so you can put everything into
                //   a separate list so that you can DML.
                // This accomplishes nothing except wasting time
                for(Case casesToUpdateSet : casesToUpdate){
                    casesToUpdateLedger.add(casesToUpdateSet);
                }
                if(casesToUpdateLedger.size()>0){
                    // I'm not sure if using the Database class method here is
                    //   appropriate.
                    // Specifying allOrNone = false, and then not perfomring
                    //   any failure handling sounds like a recipe for hard-to-detect
                    //   bugs to me.
                    Database.update(casesToUpdateLedger,false);
                }
            }   
        } 
    }             
}
```

You can take this helper class from 33 lines to 20 or less, and still retain all of the functionality.

As for your test class, it appears that you do have a grasp on how to make meaningful unit tests. I like to say that unit testing has 3 phases to it:

1. Set up the test environment so that the code you want to test will actually run
2. Execute the *one* piece of code that you want to test
3. Make assertions after the SUT (system under test) has been executed to verify results

I see you performing phases 1 and 2. I have some comments on your setup phase, but Phase 3, verifying results, is where I think the test falls short.

Again, copy/pasting with commentary:

```
@isTest
private class Case_Test {

    @isTest 
    private static void onAfterInsrt() {

        // Best practice would be putting this setup into a dedicated method
        //   with the @testSetup annotation, but I won't rag on you for that.
        // prepare test data
        ID refundRecordtypeID = Schema.SObjectType.Ledger__c.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get(SYSTEM.label.RECEIPT_RECORDTYPE).getRecordTypeID(); 

        // Preparing 20 cases seems reasonable, though your test never ends up
        //   making any assertions (like the number of queries or dml statements
        //   that your helper method uses) that necessitate creating any more than
        //   one or two test cases.
        List<case> caseDataList = new List<case>();
        for(Integer i=0;i<20;i++){
            Case caseData = new Case(Status='Open', Origin='Email');
            caseDataList.add(caseData);
        }

        // I don't see the point of using this Database method here over just
        // plain 'ol 'insert'
        // Also, if there's an issue inserting your test data, that's something
        //   that I would absolutely want to know (and cause a test failure).
        // I do not agree with allOrNone = false here.
        Database.insert(caseDataList, false);

        List <Ledger__c> receiptList = new List <Ledger__c>();

        // Why iterate from 0 to 20 instead of just iterating over the cases
        //   that were just inserted?
        for(Integer j=0;j<20;j++){
            // Iterating over inserted cases would let us remove this line.
            // If you do keep this line, this is another variable naming issue.
            // This is a case, not a case id
            Case caseID = caseDataList[j];

            // You used the SObject constructor for creating the case, but not
            //   for creating the test Ledgers?
            // Either way would work, but consistency is nice.
            Ledger__c receipt = new Ledger__c();
            receipt.RecordTypeId = refundRecordtypeID;
            receipt.Status__c = 'Open';
            receipt.CaseID__c = caseID.id;

            receiptList.add(receipt);
        }

        // Keeping the actual test isolated between start/stop test.
        // Good job.
        Test.startTest();

        // Again, I don't really agree with allOrNone = false here
        // If any record in the insert fails, you want to know about it
        Database.insert(receiptList, false);

        Test.stopTest();

        // Phase 3: assertions
        // In my opinion, the part of the test that needs the most work.

        // You do want to query the data again, prior to making assertions,
        //   so that you get the updated value of Status...
        //   but queries inside of loops are still a bad idea.
        // Again, poor variable naming (the loop variable is a single case, not a 
        //   set of case Ids)
        for(Case CaseIdSet: caseDataList){
            CaseIdSet=[SELECT Status FROM CASE WHERE Id =: CaseIdSet.id];
            System.debug('CaseIdSet-------->'+CaseIdSet);
            System.debug('Status -------->'+Case.Status);
            //ASSSERTION SHOULD BE STATUS CLOSED BUT STATUS IS OPEN ALWAYS

            // And here, you actually want to make the assertion
            // You only need to pass 2 parameters, but passing the third parameter
            //   lets you control the message that's displayed when the assertion fails.
            // Having specific assertion messages can help pinpoint what is wrong
            //   and where in the test the failure occurred.
            // System.assertEquals('Closed', case.Status, 'Expected the case to be closed');
        } 
    }
}
```

Beyond that, one test is generally not a sufficient amount of testing. If this came to me in review, I would not sign off on it.

Unit tests are your chance to prove that your code works in a variety of situations (not all of them being ideal situations). You've tested the basic "happy path", but there are many more tests that I would encourage you to write.

- What happens when a `Ledger__c` with a null `CaseID__c` comes along?
- What happens if all `Ledger__c` records have no `CaseId__c`?
- If you have 2 `Case` records, and only insert one `Ledger__c`, is it only the `Case` related to that `Ledger__c` record updated?
- What happens if you insert a `Ledger__c` that isn't of recordtype `Receipt`?